# I'm trying to add a leading zero to a time column that is saved as varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 database. One column in a table has some poorly formatted data that I need to correct.

The column is a `varchar(8)` and has data like this.

```
05:30 PM
10:00 AM
09:30 AM
5:30 PM
6:30 PM
06:30 PM
```

I need to add a leading zero to 5:30 PM and 6:30pm so that all fields are the 
same length.

```
update MeetingRegister
set sMeetingTime = REPLACE(sMeetingTime, sMeetingTime, '0'+ sMeetingTime) 
where sMeetingTime like '_:%' `
```

I think my script works if I only match one record.

How can I update all matching records in my table?

**Update**:

I should have added my error message

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vjr_trig_Meeting_Update, Line 154
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.`

And now that I do (forced me to read it closely).

I see my problem is related to a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
update MettingRegister
    set sMeetingTime = '0' + MeetingTime
    where MeetingTime like '_:%';
```

Your logic is overly complicated, but it should also work on all matching rows.

Comment: I was doing more complex matching before.  That's how my query became more complicated than it needed to be.  Thanks for pointing that out :)  I also spotted the problem is actually with a trigger (See Update above).  I think I can just disable the trigger during my update and I should be OK.